# Getting speaker feedback when I use my microphone in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, microphone

I bought a microphone to use for Skype on Ubuntu. I plugged it into my soundcard and it works in the sense that it's detecting audio, but a horrible feedback whine starts through my speakers.

I'm using Ubuntu Karmic (upgraded from Jaunty). This works fine in Windows 7. Why is it broken in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you are using a laptop then open it wider.  Sometimes a laptop with a mic near the screen and speakers on the bottom can get too close (if sound is loud) and cause feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It's not broken.  Open Sound Preferences and make sure Input is at unamplified.

Alternatively, use another mixer program and make sure mic and or line in is at zero.

Comment: Where is this setting, please? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: If you have the default gnome-panel, you should right-click on the speaker icon, then you'll find a settings button. If you don't have it, try writing within a terminal alsamixer.

Comment: System -> Preferences.  Same place as all the other preferences.

Comment: OK thanks. I can't see anything about amplification. All I can see is a selector for which sound devices to use. I'll give it a go next weekend when I have time and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to just use headphones.  Skype has some feedback-handling capabilities, but the audio is never as good as if the microphone cannot easily pick up the signal coming out of the speakers.  The best way to do this is with headphones.

Comment: It's a pity you weren't around when I asked this. http://superuser.com/questions/91584